# Checkpoint loaded pytorch lightning module has no accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, pytorch-lightning

I have a pytorch lightning module that trains and validate with no problem. I can save the best checkpoint with ModeCheckpoint but when I load the model on a different colab notebook I get 0 accuracy. I cannot understand why.

**The model**

```
class WSDModel(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self, language_model_name, num_labels, num_pos_tags, training_steps = 0, warmup_steps = 0):
    super().__init__()
    self.save_hyperparameters()

    self.num_labels = num_labels
    config = transformers.BertConfig(dropout=0.1, attention_dropout=0.1, output_hidden_states=True)
    self.bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained(language_model_name, config=config)

    self.pos_embedding = nn.Embedding(num_pos_tags, self.bert.config.hidden_size)

    for param in self.bert.parameters():
      param.requires_grad = False

    self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, num_labels, bias=False)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.13)

    self.training_steps = training_steps
    self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps

    self.train_predictions = []
    self.train_senses = []

    self.val_predictions = []
    self.val_senses = []

  def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, pos_tags):
    model_kwargs = {
        "input_ids" : input_ids,
        "attention_mask" : attention_mask,
        "token_type_ids" : token_type_ids
    }
    outputs = self.bert(**model_kwargs)
    transformers_outputs_sum = torch.stack(outputs.hidden_states[-4:], dim=0).sum(dim=0)
    transformers_output = self.dropout(transformers_outputs_sum)

    pos_embeddings = self.pos_embedding(pos_tags)

    combined_embedding = transformers_output + pos_embeddings

    logits = self.classifier(combined_embedding)

    return logits

  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    senses = batch['senses']
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
    token_type_ids = batch['token_type_ids']
    pos_tags = batch['pos_tags']

    logits = self(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, pos_tags=pos_tags)

    loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), senses.view(-1), ignore_index=-100)

    preds = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)

    correct_predictions, correct_senses = get_correct_labels(preds.tolist(), senses.tolist())

    self.train_predictions.extend(correct_predictions)
    self.train_senses.extend(correct_senses)

    self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)

    return loss

  def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        ...
    return loss

  def configure_optimizers(self):
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=2e-3)
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
      optimizer,
      num_warmup_steps=self.warmup_steps,
      num_training_steps=self.training_steps
    )

    return dict(
        optimizer=optimizer,
        lr_scheduler=dict(
            scheduler=scheduler,
            interval="step"
        )
    )


  def predict_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    input_ids = batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
    token_type_ids = batch['token_type_ids']
    senses = batch['senses']
    pos_tags = batch['pos_tags']

    logits = self(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask,token_type_ids=token_type_ids, pos_tags=pos_tags)

    preds = logits.argmax(dim=-1)
    correct_predictions, correct_senses = get_correct_labels(preds.tolist(), senses.tolist())

    return {"correct_predictions" : correct_predictions, "correct_senses" : correct_senses}
```

**The trainer**

```
wandb_logger = WandbLogger()
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath='/content/drive/MyDrive/nlp_hw2/checkpoints',
    filename='WSD_posTags-{val_accuracy:.2f}',
    save_last = True
    )
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, accelerator="auto", callbacks=[MyPrintingCallback(), checkpoint_callback], logger = wandb_logger, precision=16)
```

**The problem**

If i call

`preds = trainer.predict(model, test_dataloader)`

just after the training the model gets around 85% of accuracy but if I restart the colab notebook and load the model from the saved checkpoint it gets 0% accuracy.
 `loaded_model = WSDModel.load_from_checkpoint(PATH) load_pred = trainer.predict(loaded_model, test_dataloader)`

What Am I missing?

This seems to be the official way, suggested by the Pytorch Lighting Docs, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I also tried to save the model_state_dict with a vanilla pytorch approach but it didn't work either